# Match letter followed by specific numeric range

Tags: regex

I am writing a regular expression in which the string can be of 2-3 characters.
The first character has to be a Alphabet between A and H (capitals). This character has to be followed by a number between 1 and 12.
I wrote

```
[A-H]{1}[1-12]{1,2}
```

This is fine when I keyin `A12` but not when I keyin `A6`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify a range of digits like that because it is implemented as a range between characters, so `[1-12]` is equivalent to `[12]`, which would only match either a `1` or a `2`.  Instead, try the following:

```
[A-H](?:1[012]|[1-9])
```

Here is an explanation:

```
[A-H]        # one letter from A to H
(?:          # start non-capturing group
   1[012]      # 1 followed by 0, 1, or 2 (10, 11, 12)
   |           # OR
   [1-9]       # one digit from 1 to 9
)            # end non-capturing group
```

Note that the `{1}` after `[A-H]` in your original regex is unnecessary, `[A-H]{1}` and `[A-H]` are equivalent.

You may want to consider adding anchors to the regex, otherwise you would also get a partial match on a string like `A20`. If you are trying to match an entire string then you should use the following:

```
\A[A-H](?:1[012]|[1-9])\z
```

If it is within a larger text you could use word boundaries instead:

```
\b[A-H](?:1[012]|[1-9])\b
```

Comment: Thanks. A12 is only a partial match in this case. Only A1 is matching. http://rubular.com/r/EQmL27ZTAH

Comment: @Ankur - I just switched the order of the alternation so it should work correctly now.  You may want to consider adding anchors to the regex, otherwise you would also get a partial match on a string like `A20`.  If you are trying to match an entire string then you should use `\A[A-H](?:1[012]|[1-9])\z`, or if it is within a larger text word boundaries may help: `\b[A-H](?:1[012]|[1-9])\b`

Comment: Be aware that if you don't anchor that regex it will also match, for example, A4 in A40

Comment: won't A40 be a partial match If I am not adding anchors?  http://rubular.com/r/WoPvmBrlWQ

Comment: yes, it will partially match A4 which seems not desirable (depends on your requirements). I use ^ and $ in my answer which are also anchors.

Comment: The different anchors can be a bit confusing. A good explanation can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: Yep, anchors are a good idea here.  I prefer `\A` and `\z` over `^` and `$` because the meaning of `^` and `$` can change if a multi-line option is set.  Also `$` will match before line break characters at the end of a string, but `\z` only matches at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
^[A-H]([1-9]|1[0-2])$
```

No need to for the {1} in your question.

The regex is anchored with ^ and $ meaning it can can be the only thing on your line.
It will not match A60 for example

Comment: This is overly permissive, as it will allow (for example) `A90` or `A22`.